# highest number finding code is having errors because of try loop or while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

1. This code is supposed to find the biggest number.
2. When I plug in (200, 4, 100) in order, it says that 4 is the biggest number.
3. When I plug in numbers of similar size, it has no problem.
4. I feel like this is due to my lack of looping knowledge.
5. Can someone teach me what's the issue? (student still learning)

```
def num_max(num1, num2, num3):
    if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3:
        return(num1)
    elif num2 >= num1 and num2 >= num3:
        return(num2)
    else:
        return(num3)


while 1:
    num1 = input("#1: ")
    try:
        in1 = int(num1)
        break
    except:
        print("Invalid: Try again")


while 1:
    num2 = input("#2: ")
    try:
        in2 = int(num2)
        break
    except:
        print("Invalid: Try again")


while 1:
    num3 = input("#3: ")
    try:
        in3 = int(num3)
        break
    except:
        print("Invalid: Try again")


print("The biggest number you entered is the following:  ")
print(num_max(num1, num2, num3))
```

Comment: Additional question. I'm a math student self-teaching python. Where do I ask questions of such noobish level? This is my second question feel that this is a professional platform, I'm intimidated to ask here. Where do I go?

Comment: Don't get intimidated, as long as you correctly explain your question with clear inputs and expected/actual outputs, you're fine. Also make sure you search for other similar questions beforehand.

Comment: Yeah, beginner questions that are tricky are well-received. But if you show lack of research, or seem not to be trying, or post an unclear question, that's when the downvotes come in. This question was a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don' need a while look for inputs. This is an additional overhead and slows down your program. You should also pass your function the `int`s themselves not the strings.

This should work:

```
def num_max(num1, num2, num3):
    if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3:
        return(num1)
    elif num2 >= num1 and num2 >= num3:
        return(num2)
    else:
        return(num3)


try:
    num1 = input("#1: ")
    num2 = input("#2: ")
    num3 = input("#3: ")

    in1 = int(num1)
    in2 = int(num2)
    in3 = int(num3)
except:
    print("Invalid: Try again")

print(num_max(in1, in2, in3))
```

Comment: Yeah, without any loops, the retry won't happen automatically. I would actually prefer your while loops

Comment: @lucidbrot An infinite white loop for retries is bad design.

Comment: Depends on the use case imho. If it's a function that is called elsewhere, I agree that it should just throw an exception and let the caller deal with it - but if it's main, why not loop?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using the string `num`variables for the function, try sending just the int variables `in`, and when you compare strings, 4 is greater than 200.

Change this line:

```
print(num_max(num1, num2, num3))
```

whit this one:

```
print(num_max(in1, in2, in3))
```